# json_agg with dynamic 0-level key

Tags: json, postgresql-10, string-aggregation

I'm migrating a schema from NoSQL to postgres. Today's object "`b`" exists in NoSQL as an element of object `a` & looks in source like this...

```
{
  "a": {
    "id": 1,
    "b":{
      "c1": {
        "d1": 1,
        "d2": 2
      },
      "c2": {
        "d1": 1,
        "d2": 2
      },
      "c3": {
        "d1": 3,
        "d2": 4
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...which I've tentatively assigned to a schema resembling the below ERD

```
+---+    +-----+    +---+    +---+
| b |<--<| b_d |>-->| d |>-->| c |
+---+    +-----+    +---+    +---+
```

[full db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b11ae0d9dc40a511eafce70e8050d6d8)

I'd like to be able to recompose the normalised data into the original object but I've been unable to do so. Instead of getting "`c`" objects as direct key-value pairs, I'm getting whole objects. [For example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=90f9672dca05fb084338ab82138bc6cd&hide=15)...

```sql
select 
    b_d.b_id, 
    json_agg(json_build_object(c.name,json_build_object('d1',d.d1,'d2',d.d2))) as b
from b_d
join d on d.id = b_d.d_id
join c on c.id = d.c_id
group by b_d.b_id;
```

...returns...

```
[{
    "c1 ": {
        "d1": 1,
        "d2": 2
    }
},
{
    "c2 ": {
        "d1": 1,
        "d2": 2
    }
},
{
    "c3 ": {
        "d1": 3,
        "d2": 4
    }
}]
```

...which you will note has an additional nesting level versus the source object. I suspect I've gone wrong out of the gate with [`json_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) but so far have been unable to successfully reconstruct the "`b`" object as it appears in the original json document.

What do I modify about the query and/or the underlying schema to normalize and denormalize this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking on the json functions docs page, look instead on the [aggregate functions docs page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-aggregate.html). `jsonb_object_agg()` will aggregate the object without an additional level of nesting as seen in [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8d0e0eca0531d7a52bbeda63a0347bbc&hide=15).

```sql
select 
    b_d.b_id,
    jsonb_object_agg(c.name,json_build_object('d1',d.d1,'d2',d.d2)) as b
from b_d
join d on d.id = b_d.d_id
join c on c.id = d.c_id
group by b_d.b_id;
```

...returns the original object as desired.

```
{
    "c1 ": {
        "d1": 1,
        "d2": 2
    },
    "c2 ": {
        "d1": 1,
        "d2": 2
    },
    "c3 ": {
        "d1": 3,
        "d2": 4
    }
}
```

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43453685/4709762) [also](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/100607/68127)